# Quotes as array index [""] (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I found this notation in a javascript code:

```
this.numbers[""].x
```

I can't understand what the apices mean. What do they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `numbers` is an object which contains a key which is the empty string. Using `['']` will access the property of the object which is the empty string (and then `.x` will access the `x` property inside it).

It sounds very strange, and it is, but it's syntactically legal to construct such a thing:

```js
const numbers = {
  '': {
    x: 'valueOfX'
  }
};
console.log(numbers[''].x);
```

(If you ever see this sort of thing in code that you have control over, I'd suggest considering refactoring it to be less confusing)

Comment: Depends on what the property names in that object represent. There are cases where an empty string is totally sensible. (Thinking of some combinatorics stuff here.)